# Pig: Count number of keys in a map

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

I'd like to count the number of keys in a map in Pig. I could write a UDF to do this, but I was hoping there would be an easier way.

```
data = LOAD 'hbase://MARS1'
       USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
         'A:*', '-loadKey true -caching=100000')
       AS (id:bytearray, A_map:map[]);
```

In the code above, I want to basically build a histogram of `id` and how many items in column family `A` that key has.

In hoping, I tried `c = FOREACH data GENERATE id, COUNT(A_map);` but that unsurprisingly didn't work.

Or, perhaps someone can suggest a better way to do this entirely. If I can't figure this out soon I'll just write a Java MapReduce job or a Pig UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIZE should apparently work for you (not tried it myself):

- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SIZE